# Is there a situation when an array is not converted to pointer except of sizeof?

Tags: c

I am preparing some presentation and I am curious if there is any other context (except of sizeof) where a variable of array type gives different behavior than a pointer to the first element of the array. I mean:

```
int a[5];
int *p = a;
printf("%d %d\n", sizeof(a), sizeof(p));
```

prints two different numbers. Is there any other similar situation where it matters whether I use an array or a pointer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a situation when an array is not converted to pointer except of sizeof?

From C99/C11, section 6.3.2.1:

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, [the `_Alignof` operator,] or the unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type "array of type" is converted to an expression with type "pointer to type"...

Note that `_Alignof` is only in C11.

---

> Is there any other similar situation where it matters whether I use an array or a pointer?

The above rule explains everything about the behaviour of arrays vs. pointers.  However, there are several less-than-obvious implications of the conversion it describes.

For example, this doesn't compile:

```
void foo(int **a) { }

int b[5][10];

foo(b);  // Compilation error; b becomes &b[0], which is pointer type,
         // and thus doesn't then become &&b[0][0]
```

And neither does this:

```
int a[5];
int b[5];

a = b;   // Compilation error; a becomes &a[0], which isn't an lvalue
```

Comment: The second part of your answer, doesn't answer the question and is more a distraction than anything. It should be some comment or so, at most. The first part is incomplete, this changed with C11 which adds the `_Alignof` operator to the text you are citing.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Second part now reworded...

Answer (score 4):

One more thing.

```
int a[10];
int *pa;
```

> There is one difference between an array name and a pointer that must
>   be kept in mind. A pointer is a variable, so pa=a and pa++ are legal.
>   But an array name is not a variable; constructions like a=pa and a++
>   are illegal.

*The C programming language, Dennis M. Ritchie*

Answer (score 3):

There are a few other contexts where it is not converted such as unary `&`, if we look at the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.3.2.1` *Lvalues, arrays, and function designators* paragraph *3* it says:

> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary & operator, or is a
>   string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is
>   converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial element of
>   the array object and is not an lvalue.